# Sitecore service error when upgrading from Sitecore 9.0.1 to Sitecore 9.0.2

Tags: xconnect, upgrade

I am in the process of upgrading the Sitecore instance from 9.0.1 to 9.0.2 [9.1 is available but we don’t have a plan to do it now]. Followed the steps in the document, 
https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/A24AE0FB3EC947ACB8F6FCCFBA0CD8C3.ashx

As part of upgrading the xConnect from Sitecore XP 9.0.1 to Sitecore XP 9.0 Update 2:

1. Stopped the Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer Windows service and Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine Windows service.
2. Tried to start the services after executing the steps mentioned in the above document, but it’s keep on throwing an error.
3. Validated multiple times, but all the steps were executed as mentioned in the document.

How this can be diagnosed? It was working before executing the migration steps. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the xConnect upgrade, all files under xConnect bin folder might be replaced with the files from the upgrade package. In XConnect’s .\Website\bin folder, some of the dlls might be blocked by default, when executing the above upgrade step. [It happened in my machine and that blocks starting the service again]

Just check all the dlls, you may need to unblock those, may be run a power-shell command to just unblock all once [it won’t harm if you unblock a dll which is not blocked].

To diagnose this issue, log files will be clearly providing the details. They are located in the below folders,

- .\App_data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data\Logs
- .\App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_data\Logs

If you don't see any log, just try running the below exe files and check the logs,

- .\App_data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\maengine.exe and
- .\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\XConnectSearchIndexer.exe

Note - As you already installed Sitecore 9.0.1 and these service working as expected before the migration,

1. I don’t think that the issue is with the certificate.
2. Also it might not be an issue with any folder’s security or anything related to that.